# Funnel Visualization - Goals

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup a funnel visualization for a destination goal for mobile. The funnel is showing up however it is showing it at a session level. I want the data to show me at a User level i.e how many users went through each stage of the funnel.

How do I do that?

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very little flexibility is setting up funnels in GA - so basically, you can't. You may find the Flow charts are a better fit for you want - comparison of funnels and goal flows is here, including a detailed description of what a funnel report is showing you (which I think a lot of people using them don't realise)

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2976313?hl=en